# ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree

Tags: java, sonarqube

Today we upgraded SonarQube Java plugin from 3.2 to 3.3 (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin). Now the analysis end with failure:

```
    13:59:10 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project ingbol: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ing_trunk_sonar/sources/cib-actions/src/main/java/com/company/cib/corpo/struts/actions/IngCcsRightsAction.java': org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree -> [Help 1]
    13:59:10 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project ingbol: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ing_trunk_sonar/sources/cib-actions/src/main/java/com/company/cib/corpo/struts/actions/IngCcsRightsAction.java'
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    13:59:10    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    13:59:10    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    13:59:10    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    13:59:10    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    13:59:10 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ing_trunk_sonar/sources/cib-actions/src/main/java/com/company/cib/corpo/struts/actions/IngCcsRightsAction.java'
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    13:59:10    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    13:59:10    ... 19 more
    13:59:10 Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ing_trunk_sonar/sources/cib-actions/src/main/java/com/company/cib/corpo/struts/actions/IngCcsRightsAction.java'
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:114)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.scan(AstScanner.java:75)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:132)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:125)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:86)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    13:59:10    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    13:59:10    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    13:59:10    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    13:59:10    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    13:59:10    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    13:59:10    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    13:59:10    ... 22 more
    13:59:10 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringToStringCheck.extractName(StringToStringCheck.java:92)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringToStringCheck.onMethodFound(StringToStringCheck.java:71)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.checks.methods.AbstractMethodDetection.checkInvocation(AbstractMethodDetection.java:52)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.checks.methods.AbstractMethodDetection.visitNode(AbstractMethodDetection.java:43)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:112)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:96)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:72)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:66)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.checks.SubscriptionBaseVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionBaseVisitor.java:33)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:121)
    13:59:10    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.walkAndVisit(AstWalker.java:67)
    13:59:10    at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:107)
    13:59:10    ... 59 more
    13:59:10 [ERROR] 
    13:59:10 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    13:59:10 [ERROR] 
    13:59:10 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    13:59:10 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How to fix this?

Environment:

- SonarQube 5.1
- SonarQube Java Plugin 3.3
- Jenkins 1.611
- Sonar Runner 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. There is obviously an issue regarding how the rule `StringToStringCheck` currently handle method invocations. The rule is new and has been introduced in java plugin 3.3.

To resolve the issue and continue with the sonar analysis, simply disable rule `squid:S1858` (*"toString()" should never be called on a String object*), as it is currently enabled by default.

Due to the *End of Service* of Codehaus, I can not create the ticket to handle the issue right now, but I'll do it as soon as possible. Be sure that the issue will be fixed for version 3.4.

Comment: I can reproduce this error with the same configuration and the same rule and only in one project. However the associated Java class where this problem occurs is really too big to isolate the root cause of the failure of this rule. Is there a way to fix the issue in the code source without disabling this rule?

Comment: @michael, could you provide the link to the Jira issue ? Thanks

Comment: The problem has been fixed. Thank you.