# java.lang.ClassCastException in SonarQube analysis after Java Plugin upgrade to version 3.4

Tags: java, sonarqube

After upgrading SonarQube Java Plugin to version 3.4 the analysis fails with the followin error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project machweb: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\DVLP MW1.0 Coverage und Codeanalyse\EJBs\src\mach\logistik\entities\mMarktplatz.java': org.sonar.java.model.expression.ParenthesizedTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project machweb: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\DVLP MW1.0 Coverage und Codeanalyse\EJBs\src\mach\logistik\entities\mMarktplatz.java'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\DVLP MW1.0 Coverage und Codeanalyse\EJBs\src\mach\logistik\entities\mMarktplatz.java'
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\DVLP MW1.0 Coverage und Codeanalyse\EJBs\src\mach\logistik\entities\mMarktplatz.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:75)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:131)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:124)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:86)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:131)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.model.expression.ParenthesizedTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree
    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.getIdentifierTree(StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.java:98)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.getIdentifierTree(StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.java:92)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.isNotLoopLocalVar(StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.java:80)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.visitAssignmentExpression(StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.java:73)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.AssignmentExpressionTreeImpl.accept(AssignmentExpressionTreeImpl.java:73)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitExpressionStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:101)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.accept(ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.java:66)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitIfStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:107)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.IfStatementTreeImpl.accept(IfStatementTreeImpl.java:124)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitForStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.visitForStatement(StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.java:155)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.ForStatementTreeImpl.accept(ForStatementTreeImpl.java:118)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitIfStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:107)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.IfStatementTreeImpl.accept(IfStatementTreeImpl.java:124)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitIfStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:107)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.IfStatementTreeImpl.accept(IfStatementTreeImpl.java:124)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitMethod(BaseTreeVisitor.java:80)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:215)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitClass(BaseTreeVisitor.java:69)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:199)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55)
    at org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree$CompilationUnitTreeImpl.accept(JavaTree.java:136)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.scanFile(StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.java:67)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:94)
    ... 59 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Searching stackoverflow led me to [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484158/sonarqube-analysis-failure-after-java-plugin-upgrade-3-2-3-3.)

The solution (Upgrading to Java Plugin Version 3.4) does not work for us since we already upgraded to 3.4. Furthermore, the rule causing the error is different, it is **squid:S1643 (Strings should not be concatenated using '+' in a loop)**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.model.expression.ParenthesizedTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree
at org.sonar.java.checks.StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.getIdentifierTree(StringConcatenationInLoopCheck.java:98)
```

Deactivating the rule is a workaround, but I would still like to use the rule. Sonarqube Version is LTS (4.5.4).

Comment: which jdk version you are using..if you are using jdk 1.6 try with the jdk 1.7

Comment: It is jdk7, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the issue on my side based only on your stack trace. Could you identify and provide a simple reproducer of the issue? (You should have a string concatenation including parentheses somewhere in your file causing the exception)

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue. Unfortunately, the error occurs in a legacy class with a lot of violations of the rule. Therefore, I cannot identify the problem easily. I have already tried to extract suspicious pieces but they don´t fail the analysis as described. Do you have any more ideas on what to look for specifically?

Comment: Is there some debug flag I can activate so that the stacktrace will contain the line-number of my class where the error happens?

Comment: Sorry for delay answering you. There is currently no debug flag available to show the line numbers while running checks.The only thing you could do is to get the sources of the java plugin, go to the check source code, and use the sonar-runner in debug mode directly on your file. 
You could also provide us the file crashing the analysis, and we will look at it on our side, without. Simply create a thread in the SQ google group and you will be able to contact us privately. https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/sonarqube